# How can I use and edit UIBinder with GXT elements?

Tags: gwt, gxt, uibinder

How can I use UI Binder and how can I edit the elements wit GWT Designer (or something similar).

I would like to use GXT elements in my GWT application.

I find this tutorial. I could use the first sample xml code.
http://www.sencha.com/learn/ext-gwt-3-declarative-markup-with-uibinder/

I would like to use a designer editor

Comment: Yes you can use UI Binder with GXT but the GWT designer tool is not compatible with latest GXT versions.

Comment: What wersions should I use?

Comment: I think designer works with GXT 2, but it's very different from GXT 3. However here is a link to how make the Designer work with gxt 2. https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/features/gwt/gxt?hl=fr. if I were you, I would use GXT 3.1.0 the old fashioned way with UIBinder if you want but without designer.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any good tutorial for UIBinder with GXT 3.1.0?
I think I will do the old fashioned way. But I'm beginner with UIBinder

Comment: Sorry I don't use UIBinder, but there are some example here: http://www.sencha.com/examples/. And it's the same principle as for GWT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT designer is not compatible with latest versions of GXT (versions 3), so I you really want to use the designer it works with GXT 2. Here is a tutorial on how to do it: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/features/gwt/gxt?hl=fr.

But GXT 2 is very different from GXT 3, so I suggest you to use GXT 3.1.0 (with UIBinder if you want), which is the last released version, the old fashioned way (without designer).

Comment: Is it compatible now?